# How do you replace dots in a UIPageControl for Text?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageControl` with dot indicators, how do I replace those dots for Text, like **Page 2 of 20**.

Comment: `UIPageControl` is only for dot indicators. Use a `UILabel` instead and update on page changes.

Comment: Thanks, @KrisJurgowski actually that's what I did, just wanted to know if there was any other easier way.